# What is the name of this design style with thick outlines and simple fills?

Tags: vector, logo, style-identification

[image] [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aH0GNSdC8M)

Another example:
[image] [source](https://bytebytego.com/)

Comment: Not every style has a specific name. You could just use words that describe it, such as  coloured vector line art.